# Delete rows in excel after comparison using python/pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to delete rows after comparing names between two excel files. currently, i figured out how to compare the files and get the names that exist in both files. now, i want to delete those rows from the second file. i had to account for accents by using unidecode since namse in file one are without accents but they could have accents in second file. for example Davis Bertans is listed as Dāvis Bertāns in the second file. thank you!

```
from unidecode import unidecode
df1["Name"] = df1["Name"].apply(unidecode)  # strip accents from Name column
result = df1[~df1["Name"].str.isin(df0["Name"].unique())]  # keep only if name not in df0
```

Comment: I think you'll have to delete those rows on your datafrale and the check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: any idea how i would use result to delete from df1?

Comment: Just `df1= df1[~df1["Name"].str.isin(df0["Name"].unique())] `